# Filter object by value in typescript or javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object JobAffiliation and wanted to filter it out by JobAffiliationEnum
ex. I want JobAffiliation separately for JobAffiliationEnum.AdminPortal and JobAffiliationEnum.EmployeePortal

```
enum JobAffiliationEnum {
    AdminPortal = 1,
    EmployeePortal = 2
}

enum JobTypeEnum {
    Job1 = 1,
    Job2 = 2,
    Job3 = 3
}

const JobAffiliation = {
    [JobTypeEnum.Job1] : JobAffiliationEnum.AdminPortal,
    [JobTypeEnum.Job2] : JobAffiliationEnum.EmployeePortal,
    [JobTypeEnum.Job3] : JobAffiliationEnum.AdminPortal | JobAffiliationEnum.EmployeePortal,
    ...
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Which object you want to filter out, what are the filter criteria, what is expected output, what have you tried ?

Answer (score 1):

First we can use `Object.keys` to get an array of `JobAffiliation` object keys second filter them by equality to one of `JobAffiliationEnum` value and finally build a new object with filtered keys with reduce.

```
const EmployeePortalKeys = Object.keys(JobAffiliation) as unknown as JobTypeEnum[]
const EmployeePortal = EmployeePortalKeys.filter((key)=> JobAffiliation[key] === JobAffiliationEnum.EmployeePortal)
    .reduce((obj, key) => {
        obj[key] = JobAffiliation[key];
        return obj;
    }, {} as JobTypeEnum[])


const AdminPortalKeys = Object.keys(JobAffiliation) as unknown as JobTypeEnum[]
const AdminPortal = AdminPortalKeys.filter((key)=> JobAffiliation[key] === JobAffiliationEnum.AdminPortal)
    .reduce((obj, key) => {
        obj[key] = JobAffiliation[key];
        return obj;
    }, {} as JobTypeEnum[])
```

Comment: Thanks, @Ishaba. I'm getting errors "element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type {0:JobAffiliationEnum......}" at JobAffiliation[key]

Comment: Made an update to code a bit ugly but works

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that `JobAffiliation` is a valid JSON like:

```
const JobAffiliation = {
    "JobTypeEnum.Job1": "JobAffiliationEnum.AdminPortal",
    "JobTypeEnum.Job2": "JobAffiliationEnum.EmployeePortal",
    "JobTypeEnum.Job3": "JobAffiliationEnum.AdminPortal | JobAffiliationEnum.EmployeePortal",
    ...
}
```

You could write something like:

```
let AdminPortalArray = [];
let EmployeePortalArray = [];
Object.entries(JobAffiliation).forEach(job => {
   if(job[1].includes("JobAffiliationEnum.AdminPortal")) AdminPortalArray.push(job);
   else if (job[1].includes("JobAffiliationEnum.EmployeePortal")) EmployeePortalArray.push(job);
});

console.log(AdminPortalArray);
// this will show [{"JobTypeEnum.Job1": "JobAffiliationEnum.AdminPortal"}, {"JobTypeEnum.Job3": "JobAffiliationEnum.AdminPortal | JobAffiliationEnum.EmployeePortal"}]

console.log(EmployeePortalArray);
// this will show [{"JobTypeEnum.Job2": "JobAffiliationEnum.EmployeePortal"}, {"JobTypeEnum.Job3": "JobAffiliationEnum.AdminPortal | JobAffiliationEnum.EmployeePortal"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.entries` to enlist key value pairs and then filter them out by value and then use  `Object.fromEntries` to build the new object from that entries :

```
enum JobAffiliationEnum {
    AdminPortal = 1,
    EmployeePortal = 2
}

enum JobTypeEnum {
    Job1 = 1,
    Job2 = 2,
    Job3 = 3
}

const JobAffiliation = {
    [JobTypeEnum.Job1] : JobAffiliationEnum.AdminPortal,
    [JobTypeEnum.Job2] : JobAffiliationEnum.EmployeePortal,
    [JobTypeEnum.Job3] : JobAffiliationEnum.AdminPortal | JobAffiliationEnum.EmployeePortal
}

const filterValues = [JobAffiliationEnum.AdminPortal,JobAffiliationEnum.EmployeePortal];

const newObject = Object.fromEntries( Object.entries(JobAffiliation).filter(([k,v])=> filterValues.some( (f : number)=> (v & f) === f)))

console.log(newObject);
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8&ts=4.3.5#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)

This `(v & f) === f` tests the value `v` has the flag `f`. And beware that flag values have to be the power of 2.